# Creating XML, exporting using bulk copy

Tags: sql-server, bcp, sqlxml

I assume there is something 'unique' with using bcp alongside FOR XML and CTE's. (Maybe not?)

> How can I export XML's I created **dynamically**?
>   How to use bcp if my query implements CTE, if I use WITH NAMESPACES ?
>
> Should I 'wrap' bcp around Namespaces and CTE ? Shall I create it separately and then concatenate ?
>   I tried it all but nothing seems to work.

---

My attempt (Of course the bcp select was in the same line):

```
 ... Ansi nulls,quoted ident,created procedure,declared all variables
IF (@tabelaTipaRacuna = 'istdev')
BEGIN
SELECT @SQL = 

         'WITH XMLNAMESPACES(DEFAULT ''ba.cbbh.crr.retail''), Ent_Posta
            AS
        (
           SELECT e.naziv,p.posta,e.sifra
            FROM entitet AS e
          INNER JOIN poste AS p ON e.sifra = p.entitet
        )


          ''bcp "SELECT [dbo].[brojracuna](' + @kodBanke + ',i.partija) AS ''AccountNo/BBAN'',
           [dbo].[GENERATEIBAN](i.partija) AS ''AccountNo/IBAN'', 
           ' + '''D''' + ' AS ''AccountType'',
           (a.ime + ''('' + a.roditel + '')''  + a.prezime) AS ''Name'',
           a.embg AS ''UID'',
       CASE status 
       WHEN 2 THEN ''A'' 
       WHEN 4 THEN ''B''
       WHEN 8 THEN ''U''
  END AS ''Status'',
  c.sifra AS ''Territory'',
  ' + @kodBanke + ' as ''ID_Bank'',
  CONVERT(DATETIME,' + 'i.dotvoranje' + ',120) AS ''OpeningDate'',
  ISNULL(CONVERT(DATETIME,' + '1' + ',120),'''') AS ''ClosingDate''
 FROM adresar AS a
  INNER JOIN' + QUOTENAME(@tabelaTipaRacuna) + ' AS i 
      ON a.embg = i.embg
        INNER JOIN Ent_Posta as c
        ON a.postbroj = c.posta 
        FOR XML PATH(''Account''), ROOT(''Accounts'')"' + 'queryout' + @output + ' -c -C65001 -t";" -r"\n" -T -S' + @server;

        exec master..xp_cmdshell @sql
END
```

Procedure call:

```
EXEC [dbo].[generateXML_CRR] @tabelaTipaRacuna = istdev, @output = 
     '//111.11.11.111/share/CRR.txt', @server = '111.11.11.112'
```

---

***Edit:***

I tried to put it like this:
[image]
...

[image]

but now I receive invalid object name on one of my tables.

I hope my question will not seem vague, if so, please ask for clarification.

Printing @SQL won't indicate any syntax errors.

Comment: Did my answer help you?

Answer (score 0):

I would rather insert these XMLs to a staging table and do the `BCP` from there. But your issue can be solved too...

I think my magic crystall ball is right. It showed me, that you need help how to assing a `FOR XML`'s result to a variable and how to return a variables value out of dynamically created code. Look at this:

If the result of a statement is scalar, you can assign it within the `SELECT` directly;

```
DECLARE @SomeName VARCHAR(MAX);
SELECT TOP 1 @SomeName=name FROM sys.objects;
SELECT @SomeName;
```

And you can assign a `FOR XML`'s result (same with a simple scalar value) simply by wrapping the `SELECT` in paranthesis:

```
DECLARE @myXML XML=
(SELECT * FROM sys.objects FOR XML PATH('row'),ROOT('root'));
SELECT @myXML;
```

This would not work with a statement like this, as the `WITH` does not allow to be embedded:

```
WITH FilterObjects AS
(SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE name LIKE '%row%')
SELECT * 
FROM FilterObjects
FOR XML PATH('row'),ROOT('root');
```

But you can mix both approaches:

```
DECLARE @myXML2 XML;

WITH FilterObjects AS
(SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE name LIKE '%row%')
SELECT @myXML2=
( --wrap this and assign it
    SELECT * 
    FROM FilterObjects
    FOR XML PATH('row'),ROOT('root')
);
SELECT @myXML2;
```

Now, when you've managed to assign the `FOR XML`'s result to a variable, you must learn how to return it form dynamically created SQL:

```
DECLARE @cmd NVARCHAR(MAX)=
'SELECT TOP 1 @TheOutput=name FROM sys.objects;'; --@TheOutput "inside" is not declared yet!

DECLARE @IReadIt NVARCHAR(100); --define a variable "outside"

--Now we use sp_executesql to declare the inner variable and to bind the outer to the inner variable
EXEC sp_executesql @cmd,N'@TheOutput NVARCHAR(100) OUTPUT',@TheOutput=@IReadIt OUTPUT;

SELECT @IReadIt;
```